# Why is e.force:closeQuickAction not working when added on the first line of init function but works correctly when added within action.setcallback?

Tags: aura

I'm working with Aura components and a beginner. I don't understand why the works when added within action.setCallback, but does not work if I add it on the first line of my init method. Is it because it waits for the setCallback to execute?

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    let  recordTypeId = '0120Y000000NFqfQAG';
    console.log('rec id ---->'+recId);
    if(recId != null){
        var action = component.get("c.setDefaultOppValues");
        action.setParams({
            "recordId" : recId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state ==="SUCCESS"){
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                console.log('return val ---> '+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                var navService = component.find("navService");
                let leadValues,contactValues;
                let data = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('ret 2----->'+response.getReturnValue());
                for(var x in data){
                    x == 'Id' ? leadValues = data[x] :contactValues = data[x]; 
                }
                console.log('lead val --->'+leadValues);
                console.log('contact val --->'+contactValues);
                var defaultValues = {
                    LMS_EVT_Contact__c : contactValues,
                    LMS_EVT_Lead__c : leadValues
                  };
                var pageReference = {
                    type: 'standard__objectPage',
                    attributes: {
                        objectApiName: 'Event',
                        actionName: 'new'
                    },
                    state: {
                        recordTypeId:recordTypeId
                    }
                }
                pageReference.state.defaultFieldValues = component.find("pageRefUtils").encodeDefaultFieldValues(defaultValues);
                component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
                navService.navigate(pageReference);
            }else{
                console.log(response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
},
```